# Carriage return in TextBox concats an empty string

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting a very peculiar error when I am pressing enter in my textbox...
I have a simple textbox on my winform.

I press type the following text:

"This is my message! " with 2 carriage returns after it.

I'm trying to replace the carriage returns with a special tag named %new_line%..but when I go into the debug window inside VS2010 I get this!

Why is:

```
  vbCrlf & ""
```

being added when there is no empty string after it. It's a simple carriage return with no trailing spaces.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how the string is shown in the debug window. There are no characters after the newline.

When you have a newline in a middle of a string, it's shown as:

```
..." & vbCrlf & "...
```

There just isn't a special case for displaying the line break differently when it's at the end of a string, so you just get the `& "` to continue the string, and then the `"` to end the string.

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware of this Guffa. Thanks for pointing this out.